# ios ipad: rotating TabBar to left side in landscape mode, with transform and constraint update

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, constraints, transform

I'm creating an ios IPad app that has a UITabBar control positioned at the bottom with 3 MenuItems in it.  Normally, when I rotate the device, the tabbar will remain at the bottom in landscape.  I'd like to have the TabBar rotate to the left side in Landscape mode, and become a vertical representation.  I don't want to create a UIView with buttons if possible, because I'd like the same object to manage both, and I like the convenience of the normal TabBar.

My Plan was to detect the device position, and use a UITransform to rotate the TabBar 90 degrees when in landscape.  Let's ignore the icon and text rotation inside for now, and just focus on the overall TabBar itself.

Rotation works, except that it leaves the vertical TabBar in the bottom center of the screen looking very out of place.  The next task was to constrain it to the left wall.  Normally I am using 3 constraints to hold the TabBar to the Left/Bottom/Right sides.  I'm having a lot of trouble finding the right constraints to keep it on the left side correctly.

One main problem is that once the transform is done, height and width attributes are reversed (or also transformed) on the tabbar.  So high makes it wider on the screen, and width makes it taller.  Using top/bottom constraints along with a height of 49 is what is seemingly required, except the top/bottom +height combo causes a constraint conflict.

I'm attaching my current constraint logic which is reasonably working, yet I can't figure out why I need to hardcode these values as shown.  This was the only way to get the visual output on the left side.  I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this, perhaps without hardcoded values in there for the constants.

I'm also not sure how I'll end up rotating the text+icons as a next step.

Attached also are how it currently appears.  It is green to illustrate clearly but will ultimately be transparent, so the cutoff at the top of landscape won't be a problem.

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    switch (orientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        {
            //load the portrait view

            // revert to normal transform 
            _tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI*2);


            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintT];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintR];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintB];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintL];


            // right space
            _tabbarConstraintR =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];

            // bottom space
            _tabbarConstraintB =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];

            // left space
            _tabbarConstraintL =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];



            //[self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintT];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintR];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintB];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintL];



        }

            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            //load the landscape view
           _tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI/2);


            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintT];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintR];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintB];
            [self.view  removeConstraint:_tabbarConstraintL];
            NSLog(@"frame: %f,%f",_tabBar.frame.size.height,_tabBar.frame.size.width);


            // top space 
            _tabbarConstraintT =   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2+49];
            // left space
            _tabbarConstraintL =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:-360.0];

            // effective width
            _tabbarConstraintR = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem: nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                                               constant:49];
            // effective height
            _tabbarConstraintB = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tabBar
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem: nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                                               constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];


            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintR];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintB];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintT];
            [self.view addConstraint:_tabbarConstraintL];


        }
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown:break;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]